# Hackerrank Problem All Testcases Not Matched

Tags: c, sorting, for-loop, struct, nested-loops

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle;
void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
    /*
    * Sort an array a of the length n
    */
    int area_i ,area_j,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            area_i = (tr[i].a+tr[i].b+tr[i].c)/2;
            area_j = (tr[j].a+tr[j].b+tr[j].c)/2;
            if(area_i>area_j){
                struct triangle temp = tr[i];
                tr[i] = tr[j];
                tr[j] = temp;
            }
            
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
    }
    sort_by_area(tr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Small Triangles, Large Triangles From hackerrank**

> I have write some code in `sort_by_area` function and it worked only
> for below test case

```
3
7 24 25
5 12 13
3 4 5
```

> but other than that all testcases failed, can you please let me know
> why is the other testcase failed like the below one :

```
10
67 67 19
3 57 55
33 33 49
61 58 59
23 43 35
48 42 45
23 12 27
41 34 22
26 49 35
63 46 45
```

> Solutions are available on internet but I want to know what's wrong
> with my approach.
> [Hackerrank Problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/small-triangles-large-triangles/problem)

Comment: You are not implementing Heron's Formula correctly (and you have integer division by 2). The formula is given in the problem, although you don't need to compute the square root to make a comparison. Also, for execution time, you should compute each area² once and store in the `struct`. And consider using library function `qsort`, which should out-perform your sort.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to declare the variables `area_i` and `area_j` as having the type `double` and write

```
double area_i ,area_j;
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        area_i = (tr[i].a+tr[i].b+tr[i].c)/2.0;
        area_j = (tr[j].a+tr[j].b+tr[j].c)/2.0;
        // ...
```

On the other hand, using the Heron's formula the area is calculated like

```
p = ( a + b + c ) / 2.0;
area = sqrt( p * ( p - a ) * ( p - b ) * ( p - c ) );
```